# jQuery $.post works in chrome, safari, but not FF (claims success callback function is undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have the following jQuery 1.7.2 code:

```
var theParams = encodeURIComponent(s1)+encodeURIComponent(s2);
$.post('/myURL',theParams,processData).error(errorResponse);
function processData(data,textStatus){
    blah blah;
}// end processData
function errorResponse() {
    blah blah;
}
```

This code works fine on Safari 6 (Mac), Chrome 21 (Mac), Safari (iPad), Chrome (iPad),
but FF 14 (Mac) gives me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: processData is not defined
```

Oddly, similar code (from a different page) works just fine on FF:

```
var formData = $(form).serialize();
$.post('/myURL',formData,processData).error(errorResponse);
function processData(data,textStatus) {
    blah blah;
}// end processData
function errorResponse() {
    blah blah;
}
```

I've tried renaming the function, but that results in the same undefined error. What should I look for to debug this?

Comment: Original code also works on IE9 (Windows 7).

Comment: Are you defining functions inside if statements?  If so, that would do it: that's not allowed in JavaScript per spec, and different browsers implement it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rearranging your code

```
var processData, errorResponse, theParams;
processData = function (data,textStatus){
    //blah blah;
};
errorResponse = function () {
    //blah blah;
};
theParams = encodeURIComponent(s1)+encodeURIComponent(s2);
$.post('/myURL',theParams,processData).error(errorResponse);
```

Does this work for you ?

can you provide the `encodeURIComponent` function also please ?

Comment: This worked! All I did was move the $.post line to below the other two. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line after line 1:

```
theParams = encodeURIComponent(theParams);
```

I assume that your encodeURIComponent function is [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp).

Comment: I had tried removing the encodeURIComponent and it had no effect. See response by Saint Gerbil for fix: Have the $.post follow the processData and errorResponse functions.